# write to csv/xlsx url encode words

Tags: python, urlencode

I Have a lot of words in Hungarian that I get from an API I work with.
The words come in a url encode as far as I know.

For example, the word 'kószolgat' in Hungarian, comes from the API this way:

```
k%C3%B3szolgat
```

I would like to get the original word in Hungarian, and write it to a csv/xlsx file.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to decode data in 'utf8'.

Comment: Posting your code will make it easier to suggest how to handle it, but take a look at [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

Comment: I tried to do this: print urllib.unquote('k%C3%B3szolgat').decode('utf8'), but print prints the word kószolgat, when I'm not using print, I get u'k\xf3szolgat' in the python shell.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question instead.

Comment: @NuritIzraelov It's quite important to know the Python version as well.

Comment: the python version is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
xls = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
output_file = Workbook()
output = output_file.active
output.title = 'My data sheet'
output.append(["Title one", "Title two"])

for line in your_api:
    # Depending on a lot of encoding parameters (Your locale, the applications locale, the API locale etc)
    value_one = urllib.unquote(line[1]).decode('utf-8')
    value_two = ...
    output.append([value_one, value_two])
```

Now this solves your "write to excel" part, the encoding is tricky.
It depends on your console and your locale, and also the locale of the API.

My guess is you could probably `.decode('iso-8859-15')` or something and see if that worls, but in general most consoles use UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module does not support Unicode, but it does support 8-bit clean byte strings, so it is possible to write UTF8 encoded data to a CSV file using this module.

Since the data *appears* to be urlencoded UTF8 you can just unquote it and write it to a CSV file.

```
>>> from urllib import unquote_plus
>>> from_api = 'k%C3%B3szolgat'
>>> unquoted = unquote_plus(from_api)
>>> unquoted                   # UTF-8 encoded byte string
'k\xc3\xb3szolgat'
>>> unquoted.decode('utf8')    # returns a unicode string
u'k\xf3szolgat'
```

But you don't need to convert it to unicode in order to write it to CSV, just unquote it and write it to CSV as UTF-8:

```
import csv
from urllib import unquote_plus

with open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    from_api = 'k%C3%B3szolgat'
    writer.writerow(['some value', unquote_plus(from_api), 'another value'])
```

After running the contents of `output.csv` will be:

```
some value,kószolgat,another value
```